# Maven Multi module Spring MVC App

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven

I am trying to create an web application with spring mvc 3, jpa. In that I have different modules like core, user, account, cms, eCommerce

here account depends on core, user depends on account, cms module depends on user, eCommerce depends on user. I want to make this modules run independent (eCommerce or cms or both)

To make that I created separate web projects for core, account, user, cms, eCommerce, while coding everthing works fine, but when I try to run it using jetty:run it says

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.xxx:account:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.xxx:core:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

I created dependency like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>account</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am new to maven, can anybody help me whether to use module or dependency in this case? If module how to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your "use module or dependency" question. "Module" means a maven project that produces an artifact. "Dependency" means an artifact that a maven project depends on. As for the warnings, try doing a `mvn install` of the relevant artifacts before running jetty.

Comment: It compiled well, resulting war file contains all class files. but after running on jetty its showing classnotfound exception for classes related to core module

Comment: @Sandeep: Then those classes aren't present in the webapp. Either the core module's jar isn't being used in the webapp's classpath, or the jar doesn't contain the class(es) in question. Note that `jetty:run` doesn't run a war. It runs "in place". See the [jetty plugin page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) for descriptions of the different goals available.

Comment: Its really confusing jetty:run is throwing exception, but jetty:run-war is working fine, I created war using mvn install, is there some thing I am missing or spring dependency Injection problem?

Comment: @Sandeep: A ClassNotFoundException has nothing to do with Spring. It's a matter of classes missing from the classpath. It would help if you'd post a stacktrace of the exception. Use `mvn jetty:run -e` to turn on full error reporting, and show the output.

Comment: If I run using jetty:run its giving 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/core/domain/CoreEntity`

Comment: So the question would be where the CoreEntity class is in the war and how it got there.

Comment: CoreEntity is defined in core which is also an web application, and I created war file using maven:install, I added this war in pom.xml using dependency tag(tag is given in question)

Comment: Are you saying the core is also a webapp? Meaning it has `<packaging>war</packaging>`? If so, that shouldn't work at all without some additional monkeying around. I also noticed a problem with your dependencies that I missed before. You declared them with `<type>pom</type>`, which is almost certainly not what you want. Try removing that line to see if it helps, and if you really are depending on another war, you need to find out more about how to do that properly. I've never done it.

Comment: any way you given lot of info thanks for that, you have any comment on creating multiple war and one war depending on another, like whether it is good arch or bad arch which is not recommended?

Comment: I wouldn't have wars depending on wars. The war is an artifact that's only intended for deployment, not reusability. The basic unit of reusability at that level in Java is the jar. Jar dependencies are simple to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the POM.xml for each individual module is missing and thus Maven is unable to resolve transitive dependencies for each of the module.Here is a good read for multi-module projects in maven. http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html